# Which Sticky Scroll Header is this?

Tags: jquery, scroll, header, sticky, jquery-waypoints

Discovered the header effect found below. I know that it's using jQuery Waypoints, but I can't figure how it's swapping headers.

http://snapflow.com/product

I'd like to duplicate the effect for a presentation. If anyone has a link to the effect being used, I would appreciate a response. 
Thanks.

Comment: The application seems to be using a. https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints and b. bootstrap for other features

Comment: Can waypoints swap out the headers when changing sections? I don't see anything indicating that it can.